# How do i implement a function that check all pairs of integers X and Y based on the sum of the number of zeros in A and B = total?

Tags: python, list, function

So, i am trying to implement a function where it will check  all pairs of integers A and B such that the sum of the number of zeros in A and B = total. So, for example, if

```
def compare(numbers,total):
    if (condition):
       return True #it will return True if exists two numbers A and B in the list

    return False #it will return False if the two numbers does not exist in the list

numbers = [10,600,81000,2100000]
total = 5 #the total number of zeroes we want
print(compare(numbers,total))
```

we can see that total = 5, so we need return a pair of numbers in the list such that the number of zeroes in both numbers corresponds with the total which is 5 zeroes. So, through the function, it should display A = 600 and B = 81000 because the sum of zeroes in A and B = 5 (2 in A + 3 in B). If the sum of zeroes of A and B cannot be found in the list, for example if total = 6 meaning (zeroes in A + zeroes in B = 6), it should display A and B is not found and return False.

Comment: [Do not add "solved" or similar words to the title of a question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question). Also, [it is not necessary (and indeed, it is discouraged) to include words of thanks or other conversational elements in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question). Inappropriate edit has been rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
def compare(SEQ,Z):
    for i in SEQ:
        for k in SEQ:
            if str(i).count('0')+str(k).count('0') ==Z:
                return True
            else:
                continue
    return False
```

Comment: @MuhammadSafwan Should this case be an exception ?

Comment: yes see my answer where I put check on count

Answer (score 0):

Ok the logic is little bit complicated, but it is working fine

```
def compare(numbers,total):
    all_list = []
    for i in numbers:
        zeros = str(i).count("0")
        if zeros > 0:
            remaining_zeros = total - zeros
            if remaining_zeros > 0:
                for j in numbers:
                    if str(j).count("0") == remaining_zeros:
                        all_list.append((i,j))
    return all_list
            
        

numbers = [10,600,81000,210000]
total = 5 #the total number of zeroes we want
print(compare(numbers,total))
```